# Weighted version of the Gagliardo Nirenberg inequality

Tags: reference-request, inequalities, sobolev-spaces, norms

I'm searching for a weighted Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality similar as in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.1363.pdf where the weight is a power of the last component. Is there an inequality of the form

$$
\left(\int_E |x_k|^{\alpha} |f|^p d(x_1,\dots,x_n)\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq \left(\int_E |x_k|^{\beta} |\nabla f|^r d(x_1,\dots,x_n)\right)^{\frac{1}{r}} \left(\int_E |x_k|^{\gamma} |f|^l d(x_1,\dots,x_n)\right)^{\frac{1}{l}}
$$
for $E\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and certain $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $1\leq k <n$? If so I would be grateful for a reference!